# Why does the parser not output information to the terminal?

Tags: python-3.x

Good day, I'm new to learning Python from the word at all) The problem lies in the lack of information in the terminal, except for the completion of the code. Can you tell me what the problem is and why the titles of the films are not displayed?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.kinoafisha.info/rating/movies/2022/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
films = soup.find_all('div', class_='movieItem_title')
for film in films:
    print(film.text)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHPzO.png)

Comment: Are you sure there are any movies? Does `print(films)` produce any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are no divs with the class `movieItem_title` on the webpage (those with the class `movieItem_title` are `<a>` tags), only divs with the class `movieItem_info`.

If you change it to this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.kinoafisha.info/rating/movies/2022/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
films = soup.find_all('a', class_='movieItem_title')
for film in films:
    print(film.text)
```

It starts printing out:

```
Своя война: Шторм в пустыне
Аманат
1941. Крылья над Берлином

(and more...)
```

When you are parsing websites, I recommend using the built-in browser developer tools. They are extremely useful. You should also try going through your code and thinking through all the variants that could go wrong before asking here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks :3
Sorry for my stupidity xd

Comment: @DISSRIAR You're welcome... and we learn through mistakes:) 

I also write bad code, and then I debug it painfully (sometimes failing completely), but I think I always get a little bit farther next time... I'm sure you'll be _also_ a lot better next time you code.